# Android Location Service stopped

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I implemented a location listener inside of a service using locationManager that reports the location of the phone for every x seconds and y meters. It is initialized using the "best provider". The service runs in the background after app is exited. This seems to work fine, I am driving along the highway and getting locations ok. However, it seems to "stop" reporting sporadically. All the sudden the service stops and I have to restart my app to resume reporting. I am fairly new at this, so apologies in advance. Is there something that could be stopping my service? I tried inserting code into the service's "onDestroy" method but it is not being reached, and I am catching any unhandled exceptions and I appear to have none of those either. Could the android os be stopping my service, or perhaps my listener is being stopped somehow?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and relevant code please?

Answer (score 0):

Android stops processes if it goes out of memory or is an empty process. It deletes the process based on the following importance.

First it kills the processes of `IMPORTANCE_EMPTY = 500;` followed by `IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND = 400;`, `IMPORTANCE_SERVICE = 300;`, `IMPORTANCE_CANT_SAVE_STATE = 170;`, `IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE = 130;`, `IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE = 200;` and `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND = 100;`

What kind of phone are you using? If there are extensive apps been used at the same time the framework can kill a few background apps to recover memory.

You could add logs in [onLowMemory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onLowMemory%28%29) and in [onTrimMemory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) and check whether these are called. Also, log the integer argument in `onTrimMemory`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to restart the service if it is killed? I need this running in the background at all times.